# How to determine which modifier caused transaction to fail?

Tags: solidity

When applying modifier like isOwner, or hasFunds to a method the log at least in remix does not indicate in detail the name of the modifier but only that a given function has failed.  Is there anyway to determine which modifier failed on the function without debugging? How exactly should one use debugging to see this? Should events be issued in modifier or not to record pass or failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to determine it other than debugging (with Remix, for example).

Modifiers just "replace" the code after the `_;` with the code of the function, so the inner workings are just the same as if you added the line of code inside the function, thus, just as when a normal function fails due to a throw/revert, you don't get any info about what caused the failure or where it happened.

Firing events won't help either as the whole transaction rolls back if the execution fails at any point, this includes emitted events. If you have 2 modifiers and one passes and the other one fails, you won't see the event for the one that passed.

All you can do is to either debug with Remix to be able to see where it is failing, or just keep removing the modifiers one at a time to isolate the point of failure.